# Rails how to set the Backup gem to another dir?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-backups

After install and generate the Backup the Backup folder with the model, config, and logs goes to user home directory,

so, how to create the Backup to another dir?
for exemple i would like to create to `/data`

no i mean
the entire backup folder
for exemple
if you genterate a backup
like this
backup generate:model --trigger=db_backup --databases='postgresql' --storages=‘dropbox’ --compressor='gzip' --notifiers='mail'
will generate a folder Backup with everything
the config file
the log folder
and where the backups stays
but generate at /home/ubuntu
i would like to generate on another dir

someone know how?

Comment: You mean the backup gem? You can easily change the backup storage directory by passing desired path to `store_with` method, see http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/getting-started/

Comment: yes, 

no i mean
the entire backup folder
for exemple
if you genterate a backup
like this
backup generate:model --trigger=db_backup --databases='postgresql' --storages=‘dropbox’ --compressor='gzip' --notifiers='mail'
will generate a folder Backup with everything
the config file
the log folder
and where the backups stays
but generate at /home/ubuntu
i would like to generate on another dir

Comment: Well, you can create your backup config file in any directory you want and run the generator with `--config-file` option, passing your config file path (http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/generator/); is that what you need?

Comment: i would like the entire Backup dir and not just the backup config file

Comment: is that possible?